# is there a IE javascript command which will reprocess class definitions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I am dynamically building style tags which have classes and css data inside of them.  It seems after looking at it, that IE will not rerender items with those style classes.  Inline still works, but going to a class, and changing values inside of those classes does not update all tags WITH that class

I was curious if there is a javascript command i can use in IE to refresh/rerender the page based on the current style tags on the page?

It works in chrome, but it seems that IE doesnt do this rerender.

This is a big issue since the users can define their own styles on a page i created, so there are 2 concepts at hand:   On load:  loading the last set of style tags (during js runtime) and the edit / save of the ones created in this session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into it with IE, it seems that adding style tags with Rules in it, does not mean that these *rules* are going to applied to the document.styleSheets run-time CSS.

On the contrary, it seems that the css is scraped first.  so when it is loading controls, has something to look at for rendering.

To Get around this, I have not seen any "repaint" functions in JavaScript as of yet, but i did notice that you can actually change the rules of the CSS in the run-time, by looking at document.styleSheets object

You can add rules dynamically via JavaScript which will take effect immediately.

With that said, it might be smart to create a setter/getter for this so everything is smooth and simple to understand.  The reason for setters and getters is that you can easily find the objects that you added (Just in case you needed to remove, modify, or append to them later.

The MS page i found is:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533039(v=vs.85).aspx

Although is it archived as of 2011, i felt it relevant.

If anyone has more up to date information, i would appreciate it, but that is what was found on my end.